# Need help understanding this python code snippet with re.compile()

Tags: python

I am a beginner with python. I am trying to use a script that has the below code as a part of it. I have a couple of questions regarding this code snippet.

the current working directory has two directories cpt.133131313/ and cpt.38282382328/. I am giving these two directories as arg1 and arg2.

- What exactly is happening in `"cpt." + arg + ".\d+`?
- What should be arg so that the `if re.compile("cpt." + arg + ".\d+").search(f)` returns true?

  ```
  allfiles = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
  cpts = []
  for arg in args:
      found = False
      for f in allfiles:
          if re.compile("cpt." + arg + ".\d+").search(f):
              found = True
              cpts.append(f)
              break
      if not found:
          print "missing checkpoint: ", arg
  ```

Thanks.

Comment: Start with the docs : http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `"cpt." + arg + ".\d+"` merely concatenates strings. If `arg` is `"cpt.133131313"`, then the result is `"cpt.cpt.133131313.\d+"`.
- `arg` can be any pattern that matches up to 7 digits or arbitrary characters. If `arg` were to be the *empty* string, your pattern would match, but so would `"......."`.

Your initial prefix and postfix (`cpt.` and `.d\`) match:

- the literal text `"cpt"` plus one arbitrary character (`.` in regular expressions match one character, whatever that may be).
- One arbitrary character plus at least one digit.

The following pattern would match your directories more concisely:

```
"cpt\.\d+"
```

because that matches the literal text `"cpt."` (noe the escaped `\.` there) and 1 or more digits. You do not need to use string concatenation to achieve that.

Note that if you wanted to take user input from the command line, you *probably* want to use the [`re.escape()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) on those strings to escape any regular expression meta characters in the string.

Depending on what you are trying to do you should consider **not** using regular expressions as well perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), but...

1: `"cpt." + arg + ".\d+"` is doing a string concatenation with arg.  So if arg is, say, "blah" then this will result in the string `"cpt.blah.\d+"`.  `re.compile` then compiles this into a regex.

2: `search()` will return True if `f` matches the regex that gets compiled.